# oTree - form widget made of buttons

Tags: forms, widget, otree

I would like to make a form in oTree that consist of buttons, the user will choose his answer by clicking one of the buttons.
The build-in widget aren't good enough.
Is there a way to build this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this topic is covered in oTree documentation: 
https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html?highlight=button#buttons

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
In this way I can't submit the data that was chosen in the non-submit button.
I want the user to choose the button 1 and submit it when coosing the second button.
[attached an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSiFC.png)